# Best Design for a Table in BigTable

Tags: google-cloud-bigtable

I have a workload that I need to migrate a table to BigTable with the next information:

- Social Security Number (SSN)
- 600 values of Score for each SSN. This number of Scote can increase in the next years.

We have about 240 million of SSN.

The table must be prepared for queries looking for 1 to 10 Score for a range of 1,000 to millions of SSN.

**Which design would suit this solution?:**

**Option A:**

- Use only a SSN as RowKey
- Create each Score as a Column

Example:

Rowkey    Columns

123456789 S1:100 S2:200 S3:300 S4:400 ..... S600:600

234567890 S1:101 S2:201 S3:301 S4:401 ..... S600:601

**Option B:**

- Use SSN and Score as RowKey
- As a Column, I only have a value of Score

Example:

Rowkey         Columns

123456789#S1   Score:100

123456789#S2   Score:200

123456789#S3   Score:300

123456789#S4   Score:400

.....

123456789#S600 Score=600

234567890#S1   Score:101

234567890#S2   Score:201

234567890#S3   Score:301

234567890#S4   Score:401

.....

234567890#S600 Score:601

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/schema-design) of Best Practice regarding [Columns](https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/schema-design#columns) and [Column Families](https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/schema-design#column-families) I understand that the second approach you offer would be the most adequate, as there is the recommendation of avoiding the usage of too many columns in any single row.

You could also group the columns of the first approach in a Column Family, as there is the recommendation of grouping similar columns in column families.

I see that following the second option you also follow a good practice in treating column qualifiers as data, which overall makes me think it would be the most appropriate decision.

You can see some examples in the provided documentation and further information on best practices to build your tables in Big Table.